# Samsung Galaxy S3 shows up in Device Manager but not in Explorer

Tags: connection-issues, usb-connection-mode, android-pc

I'm trying to connect my Galaxy S3 to my computer so I could transfer some files, but my computer doesn't seem to be recognizing it.

I've already followed instructions [found here](http://www.wikihow.com/Fix-Samsung-Galaxy-S3-That-Won%27t-Connect-to-Your-PC) about putting the phone in download mode and then re-plugging it in.

Strangely, when I look in Device Manager, my computer **does** notice my device.
[image: Device Manager]

Why does Device Manager notice it but Explorer not? Is there any way without Explore to access my files on my phone?

Comment: Try changing how it is connecting to all the different options (Media Storage, Camera, etc.)

Comment: @TristanWiley where do I see that?

Comment: @Imray A notification will be there in the Notification drawer of your phone. It has the options. Otherwise, try this answer http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35023/galaxy-nexus-wont-connect-via-usb/54261?s=1|0.4393#54261 Go to **Storage** wherever it shows up in your phone Settings.

Comment: Have you tried using the Samsung Kies pc application?  Aside from that, make sure you have up to date drivers.